# Is this shoe lacing technique effective at preventing blackened toe nails?

Tags: physiology, healthcare, sport

See:

- [Reddit: LPT: How to lace your running shoes (June 7, 2015)](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/38xryo/lpt_how_to_lace_your_running_shoes/)
- [Reddit: Black toes from ultimate? (May 20, 2015)](https://www.reddit.com/r/ultimate/comments/36o74t/black_toes_from_ultimate/)
- [Runner's World: How To Lace Shoes: Prevent Black Toe Nails (March 4, 2011)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170311171054/http://www.runnersworld.co.za/shoes-gear/shoe-essentials/how-to-lace-shoes-prevent-black-toenails/)

They link to these photos:

[image: shows different lacing techniques for running shoes: 1. Black toenail, 2. Heel slipping, 3. High instep, 4. Narrow forefoot, 5. Overall roomier fit, 6. Wide forefoot]

[image: lacing diagram: left lace goes from aglet to toe, right zig zags through every hole]

The claim is that this lacing technique is effective at protecting the toenail on your big toe from being blackened ([subungual hematoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subungual_hematoma)).

Is this true?

---

The most authoritative source that I found was (Adams, Brian B. "Traumatic Injuries to the Nails and Toes." Sports Dermatology (2006): 262-281), which says:

> Lacing techniques can prevent the foot from freely slamming into the toe box, especially on downhill courses when there is a great deal of force pushing the toenail into the end of the shoe.

However, he simply asserts that without reference to empirical evidence, so it seems to be just a restatement of the claim.

I also found a chapter/article (Werd, Matthew B. "Athletic Shoe Lacing in Sports Medicine." In Athletic Footwear and Orthoses in Sports Medicine, pp. 79-87. Springer New York, 2010.) that repeats this claim, and calls the technique the "**Distal–Medial Eyelet Lacing Technique**", but again, there are no references or any mention of empirical evidence. He says that the purpose is to "pull the upper material off of the big toe and decrease the pressure on the great toe and joint".

Comment: @nomenagentis The lacing pattern is shown in "Mathematics: What is the best way to lace your shoes?" Nature 420, 476 http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v420/n6915/full/420476a.html , but that still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: and also in "The Shoelace problem" http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/92-032.pdf where it is referred to as "shoe shop quick lacing" or "shoe shop lacing", but that doesn't answer the question either.

Comment: The first paper mentions nothing about subungual hematoma.

Comment: @nomenagentis: You show 7 different shoe lacing techniques in screenshots, which one are you asking about?

Comment: @nomenagentis: Oh, okay. I found evidence showing that [Zig Zag](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/zigzaglacing.htm) lacing technique is effective. But that is slightly different than the technique you have in mind.

Comment: Wonder how much trimming toenails back would impact this condition.

Comment: It seems to me that 7 years later there is an abscence of evidence presented, which to me suggests that the effects are overstated. From personal experience, a smaller shoe size leads to black toes when running longer distances, a larger sho size less so.

Comment: @ghellquist Seconded.  I'm a hiker--and blackened toenails on downhills is even more of an issue for us because we do so much more of it.  I've never seen mention of anything about lacing other than it needs to be secure.  Protecting your toenails is all about shoe size.